# how can I use react router with 'django'

Tags: reactjs, django

I wanna use react as frontend with django as backend
I tried

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('api/',include('api.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',include('frontend.urls')),
]
```

frontend is the app contains react

frontend app urls

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('/',index)
]
```

```
def index(request):
    return render(request,'frontend/index.html')
```

i wanna use index.html any other route

Answer (score 5):

project/urls.py

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('api/',include('api.urls')), 
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('frontend.urls')), # This has to be the last item!
]
```

frontend/urls.py

```py
#...
from django.urls import re_path
#...
urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r".*", index) # RegExpr: any character is correct
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Django routing and react routing don't have to mix. They are completely separate from each other. You get your API data from the django routes and then create you own routes on the front-end with react-router. Read this for some context: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/build-a-to-do-application-using-django-and-react.

Comment: That's only correct if you have a standalone frontend. If you are using django to serve your frontend e.g. in some kind of hybrid architecture using react only on some pages, you have to "bypass" the server side django routing with some kind of wildcard urls to allow the client side router doing his job.